# How to change React-Hook-Form defaultValue with useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am creating a page for user to update personal data with React-Hook-Form.
Once paged is loaded, I use `useEffect` to fetch the user's current personal data and set them into default value of the form.

I put the fetched value into `defaultValue` of `<Controller />`.
However, it is just not showing in the text box.
Here is my code:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import { URL } from '../constants';

const UpdateUserData = props => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
    const { handleSubmit, control} = useForm({mode: 'onBlur'});

    const fetchUserData = useCallback(async account => {
        const userData = await fetch(`${URL}/user/${account}`)
                            .then(res=> res.json());
        console.log(userData);
        setUserData(userData);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const account = localStorage.getItem('account');
        fetchUserData(account);
    }, [fetchUserData])

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        // TODO
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <label>User Name:</label>
                    <Controller
                        as={<input type='text' />}
                        control={control}
                        defaultValue={userData ? userData.name : ''}
                        name='name'
                    />
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <label>Phone:</label>
                    <Controller
                        as={<input type='text' />}
                        control={control}
                        defaultValue={userData ? userData.phone : ''}
                        name='phone'
                    />
                </div>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateUserData;
```

The called API is working well and the value is actually set to `userData` state.

```
{
  name: "John",
  phone: "02-98541566"
  ...
}
```

I also tried to `setUserData` with mock data in `useEffect()`, and it doesn't work either.
Is there any problem in my above code?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what are you trying to achieve can you explain more.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use **setValue** (https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue).

Import it from useForm:

```js
const { handleSubmit, control, setValue} = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur' });
```

Then call it with the user data after it's received:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
        setValue([
            { name: userData.name }, 
            { phone: userData.phone }
        ]);
    }
}, [userData]);
```

You can remove the default values from the form.

EDIT: See alternative answers below if this does not work.

Comment: looking for typescript version of setValue for all FormValues at once

Comment: @tommcandrew
 You are right, but we still need to add defaultValues to the form.

Comment: how can setValue be used for checkboxes and radio buttons?

Comment: did not work for me. got path split error. rather answer below worked.

Comment: I'm guessing the `setValue` definition has changed since this answer was written.  It now takes a single name and value, as in `setValue(fieldName, fieldValue)`.  Setting a single field works with this method works; but is unfortunately not the goal.

Comment: This is working fine, but isDirty falg is set to true. Is there a way without making isDirty falg to true.

Comment: @SridharNatuva yes , **setValue(fieldName, fieldValue, {shouldDirty: boolean});**

Comment: @emragins You can use methods such as replace or update for field array, however, they will cause the component to unmount and remount for the targeted field array.

Answer (score 176):

@tam's answer is halfway to what is needed to make it work with version 6.8.3.

You need to provide the default value but also to useEffect to reset. That particular distinction is required if you have a form that you reload with another entity. I have a complete example in [CodeSanbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usereacthookformdefaultvalue-h6d71?file=/src/MyForm.tsx).

**In a nutshell,** you need to define your `defaultValues` in the `useForm`:

```
const { register, reset, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: useMemo(() => {
        return props.user;
    }, [props])
});
```

Then you need to listen to potential change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    reset(props.user);
}, [props.user]);
```

The example in the Code Sandbox allows swapping between two users and have the form change its values.

Comment: This is definitely one of the cleaner answers here.

Comment: @ Patrick, this works. Just a doubt when i tried without wrapping in the useMemo also it worked, the reason why we are using useMemo is that it won't recalculate on the next render until unless any of the dependency changed. Also any other diff using a useMemo and without using a useMemo directly passing the object since useEffect is already there? Can you correct me if this wrong - New to react :)

Comment: Just curious why are you using useMemo here?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Please explain why useMemo is used

Comment: You don't have to put second snippet in useEffect. Component will rerender on props change anyway. It would've work without wrapping in useEffect.

Comment: Hi @Patricks, can u please give me this question answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76859696/react-hook-form-dynamic-add-form-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 56):

`setValue` didn't work for me. Alternatively, you can use the [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset/) method:

> Reset either the entire form state or part of the form state.

Here is working code:

```js
 /* registered address */
const [registeredAddresses, setRegisteredAddresses] = useState([]);

const { register, errors, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm <FormProps> ({
    validationSchema: LoginSchema,
});

/**
 * get addresses data
 */
const getRegisteredAddresses = async () => {
    try {
        const addresses = await AddressService.getAllAddress();
        setRegisteredAddresses(addresses);
        setDataFetching(false);
    } catch (error) {
        setDataFetching(false);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getRegisteredAddresses();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (registeredAddresses) {
        reset({
            addressName: registeredAddresses[0].name,
            tel: registeredAddresses[0].contactNumber
        });
    }
}, [registeredAddresses]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, `reset({ ...reduxState })` is what I had been looking for to retain consistency between formState and reduxState.

Answer (score 35):

Found another easy way, I used `reset` API from useForm

```js
 const { handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm({ resolver });
```

After you call API and get back response data, you call `reset` with new apiData, make sure apiData key's are same as input keys (name attribute):

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    reset(apiData);
  }, [apiData]);
```

form's default values are cached and hence once you get the data from API, we reset the form state with new data.

Comment: You dont need useEffect, just do this when you have recieved the apiData directly in the .then section.

Comment: That works too, It depends on Implementation as usually API calls and handling data are made in different files. @RollingInTheDeep

Answer (score 21):

@tommcandrew's **setValue** parameter formatting didn't work for me.

This format did:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const object = localStorage.getItem('object');
  setValue("name", object.name);
}, [])
```

Comment: This is working for me with React Native and a controller wrapper.

Comment: At last. I did it. Thanks bro

Answer (score 16):

although this post is 2 months old, I stumbled upon this issue today and searched for a couple of ways to do it. The most effective way I've come up with is using useMemo to set your defaultValues, like this :

```js
const { control, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    reValidateMode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: useMemo(() => yourDefaultValues, [yourDefaultValues]),
});
```

This allows you to properly set values in your form, without the struggle of multiple implementations if you happen to have field arrays (which was my case).

This also works while using the [advanced smart form component exemple](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#SmartFormComponent) from the official documentation. Let me know if you have any questions !

Comment: I am running on 6.8.3 and the default value gets reevaluated each time the `yourDefaultValues` change but nothing happens on the form (I added debug statement in the useMemo). I have verified that the name are the same from the `name` of the component and the components are using `inputRef`and `register`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Repro link: https://codesandbox.io/s/usereacthookformdefaultvalue-h6d71?file=/src/MyForm.tsx

Answer (score 9):

This works for nested objects (I'm using version 6.15.1)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        setValue(key, value, {
            shouldValidate: true,
            shouldDirty: true
        })
    }
}, [data])
```

Comment: cleanest implementation imo

Comment: Although, eslint won't like the `for of` loop.  A possible solution is `Object.keys(data).forEach((val, i) => {})`

Comment: this doesnt work, when you reset form you get empty fields and not with defaultValues. reset() instead of setValues mostly works but its flaky and loads undefined async values if you have few of them, i am still looking for proper solution

Answer (score 5):

As of react-hook-form 7.41, you can use defaultValues with async functions like this:

```
const {
  formState: { isLoading },
} = useForm({
  defaultValues: fetch('API'),
  // resetOptions: {
  //   keepDirtyValues: true
  // }
});
```

now the defaultValue field type look like this:

```
type AsyncDefaultValues<TFieldValues> = (payload?: unknown) => Promise<TFieldValues>;
```

*isLoading* for the async defaultValues loading state.

Comment: The most up to date answer

Comment: If you're fetching data inside the defaultValues key, this is either assuming that react-hook-form is going to be your state management tool or you're duplicating network requests. If you were using something like RTK Query, or Zustand, you'd want to make your calls in there and pass the data on to the forms, not having react-hook-form be the source of truth for your data.

Comment: i am using this method, how can i pass an default Image/avatar  to control like webphoto?

Answer (score 4):

Using `reset` is a simple solution.

```
const { reset } = useForm();


onClick={()=> reset({ firstname: 'Joe' }, { lastname: 'Doe' }) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation mentions a way to set the default values if the state changes here https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#values

```js
function App({ values }) {
  useForm({
    values  // will get updated when values props updates       
  })
}
```

I have had issues reseting the form using above method, as it is leading to an infinite loop.

```
react hook form Maximum update depth exceeded
```

So, instead i tried to reset these values using useEffect, but still it did not worked.

Now, i realised that if i have to reset entire form, then i have did something like below and it worked.

```html
  useEffect(()=>{
    reset({...dataFromApi});
  }, [quote])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 7, you may no longer need useEffect to do "loading defaultValue from async call (e.g. fetch)" on the form component **mounts**

example from v7.47 [doc](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues):

```js
// set default value async
useForm({
  defaultValues: async () => fetch('/api-endpoint');
})
```

note:

1. that async function defined in `defaultValues` should return the object required for `defaultValues`
2. the call (`defaultValues()`) will be made on component mounts (same as useEffect with empty dependency array)
3. if you need other dependency, use `reset()` to load your `defaultValues` (because they are cached)

Comment: This approach works, but I really don't see why you need to do all of this in the component itself. See my other reply here about using the HOC approach

Answer (score 0):

```
 // single value change
    useEffect(() => {
        setValue("username", 'changed username', {
            shouldValidate: true,
            shouldDirty: true,
            shouldTouch: true
        })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

we can set the default values of hook forms using reset provided by react-hook-forms

```
const { handleSubmit, control,reset} = useForm();
```

```
    const fetchUserData = useCallback(async account => {
        const userData = await fetch(`${URL}/user/${account}`)
                            .then(res=> res);
        console.log(userData);
        if(userData.status===200||userData.status===201){
            reset(userData.data);
        }
    }, []);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
        const account = localStorage.getItem('account');
        fetchUserData(account);
        
    }, [fetchUserData])
```

this sets the values of the fields in form with the data fetched.
this works only when the field names in both form and fetched matches.
you can also specify the type of data for forms using interface if you are using typescript.

> interface

```
interface props{
name:string,
id:number
}
```

> useForm

```
const { handleSubmit, control,reset} = useForm<props>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

`sessionData` is the result of fetching data

```
useEffect(() => {
  sessionData &&
    reset({
      name: sessionData?.user?.name,
      username: sessionData?.user?.username,
      email: sessionData?.user?.emails.email,
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    });
}, [sessionData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few years old but I stumbled upon it and found that there is now a better way than the accepted answer.

The documentation now has a prop called `values` that will reactively update (see https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#values).

Here is the example code:

```
function App() {
  const values = useFetch("/api")

  useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    },
    values, // will get updated once values returns, this can be a state variable like OP's userData state variable.
  })
}
```

Comment: As a side note, to fetch data from the server I value using something like react-query or TRPC which makes it cleaner not having to manage useEffect hooks or state variables yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to do this that I may have missed in the comments or in one of the answers.

Just send your `defaultValues` in as a prop to the form itself.

This higher order pattern works quite a bit better.

```js
<UpdateAppointmentForm defaultValues={query.data} />
```

When I fetch from my system, I have the model I'm working with populated. Passing it directly down to the function ensures it re-renders with the data in the way I need.

In the `<UpdateAppointmentForm>` component, I can just use the `useForm` hook with the values instantiated:

```js
interface Props {
  defaultValues: SchemaType;
}

export const UpdateAppointmentForm = (props: Props) => {

  const form = useForm<SchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(Schema),
    reValidateMode: "onBlur",
    shouldFocusError: true,
    defaultValues,
    //...other stuff
  });

  // ... return your form
}
```

The approaches in here to manipulate the state on the fly just add unnecessary complication and other state juggling you really don't need to worry about. Let React's rendering cycle and component tree do the work for you.

Happy coding!