# Localize date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I had a working solution for date-fns using the following:

```
const formatMonth = format("MMM");
```

Then I imported the locale and tried the following:

```
import { de } from 'date-fns/locale';

const formatMonth = format("MMM", {locale: de});
```

Getting the error: RangeError: Invalid time value. How do I change the language to german? The docs kinda suggest exactly the same, but it's not working.

**EDIT:** Maybe that is relevant and showcases, why the new Date() is not necessary for the format:

```
const months = eachMonthOfInterval({
    start: startOfYear(value),
    end: endOfYear(value)
});
{months.map((month) => (
   <ListboxOption
     key={month.toDateString()}
     value={month}
     date={formatMonth(month)}
     disabled={!isOlderThen18Years(month)}
   ></ListboxOption>
))}
```

Also, this code works in code sandbox, but won't in my react application. Still throwing an error: RangeError: Invalid time value.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { de } from 'date-fns/locale';

const date = new Date();

console.log( format(
  date, 'MMM', 
{ awareOfUnicodeTokens: true, locale: de}
) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the FP version to format a date you need to use the `formatWithOptions` function to pass the locale options.

```
import format from "date-fns/fp/formatWithOptions";
```

It has a slightly different function signature then the `format` function, where you need to pass the options as the first argument.

```
const formatMonth = format({ locale: de }, "MMM");
```

[image: Edit happy-hill-2e0mb]

Comment: You saved my life twice already ! thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the Date as the first Parameter. For an example,

```
const formatMonth = format(new Date(),"MMM", {locale: de}); <br>
```

**OR**

```
const formatMonth = format(new Date(10/28/2021),"MMM", {locale: de});
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunally sstill same error. It worked without new Date(), when I was not defining the format...