# React Hook Form won't show error messages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a pretty tricky birthdate validation.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-react-hook-form-zimjp)

As soon as the user tries to put a birthdate younger than 18 years old, the form updates to the date of today minus 18 years. Now, as I've been looking into it more closely, somehow I wish to integrate a notice, so that the user basically is aware, that his/hers birthdate was not accepted. For this I was trying to show a span handling an error message in my Form Component:

```
{errors.birthdate && (
   <span className="text-xs text-red-700">
      {errors.birthdate.message}
   </span>
)}
```

I also have a function for validation there:

```
const validate = (date) =>
  isOlderThen18Years(date) || "You must be at least 18 years old";
```

What is happening, as for resetting a date I am using useEffect in SelectBirthDay:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOlderThen18Years(value)) {
      onChange(
        set(new Date(), { year: getYear(value) }),
      );
    }  
  }, [value, onChange]);
```

So this resets the date, but how do I show the error message? So both is happening simultaneously? Surele I could work with some kind of alert. But is it possible to actually show the span in Form Component depending on useEffect outcome in selectBirthDay component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close by passing the error message to your `onChange` handler in `<SelectBirthDay />`.

I think a good option would be to separate your date selection as a component and then just handle the info message there. This way it's separated from the `<Form />` component which doesn't have to know about this info message for the user as it is not really a validation message for the form field.

I also would suggest to move the generation of the years to the `<SelectBirthYear />` component.

**`<SelectBirthDate />`**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { SelectBirthDay } from "./SelectBirthDay";
import { SelectBirthMonth } from "./SelectBirthMonth";
import { SelectBirthYear } from "./SelectBirthYear";

export const SelectBirthDate = ({ onChange, ...field }) => {
  const [invalidMessage, setInvalidMessage] = useState();

  const handleChange = (value, invalidMessage) => {
    onChange(value);
    setInvalidMessage(invalidMessage);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="sm:col-span-2 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-2">
        <div className="mt-1">
          <SelectBirthYear onChange={handleChange} {...field} />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-1">
          <SelectBirthMonth onChange={handleChange} {...field} />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-1">
          <SelectBirthDay onChange={handleChange} {...field} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <span className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">{invalidMessage}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

**`<SelectBirthDay />`**

```js
export const SelectBirthDay = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (date) => onChange(set(value, { date: date.getDate() }));

  const days = eachDayOfInterval({
    start: startOfMonth(value),
    end: endOfMonth(value)
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOlderThen18Years(value)) {
      onChange(
        set(new Date(), { year: getYear(value) }),
        "Selected Date was not older then 18 years - automatically reset to the earliest possible date"
      );
    }
  }, [value, onChange]);
  
  return ...
```

**`<Form />`**

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="birthdate"
  rules={{ validate }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <SelectBirthDate {...field} />
  )}
/>
{errors.birthdate && (
  <span className="text-xs text-red-700">
    {errors.birthdate.message}
  </span>
)}
```

[image: Edit validation-react-hook-form (forked)]

Comment: Actually as you said, it's not really a from error anymore, so rules can be taken out of the form as well as the errors.birthdate. validate function is always going to be olderthan18, as the components reset the birthdate anyway. Am I getting it right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you're right - you could remove `validate` in `<Form />` for now.  I guess you could than also move `isOlderThen18Years` from `<Form />` to `<SelectBirthDay />` - this way `<Form />` won't contain any logic anymore about the implementation details of `<SelectBirthDate />`. It's a bit cleaner and follows the SoC principle.