# Set default values in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to check in a RHF if the user has modified the form values with the `isDirty` parameter.

Setting the defaultValues manually works:

```
const {handleSubmit, control, setValue, setError, setFocus} = useForm({defaultValues: {name: ""}});
```

This seem to work correctly.

But when the user tries to edit a form I load the values into the form with `setValue`.

Now I don't know how I can set programatically the defaultValues.

[How to change React-Hook-Form defaultValue with useEffect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242657/how-to-change-react-hook-form-defaultvalue-with-useeffect/62243132#62243132)

This is how I do, but the answer is not really correct. The values are set, but the defaultValues don't change this way so RHF can't compare.

> Make sure to provide all inputs' defaultValues at the useForm, so hook form can have a single source of truth to compare whether the form is dirty.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate

How can I set the defaultValues dynamically so it even works in 'edit' mode?

Comment: have you tried ``reset({...defaultValues})``?

Comment: After setting values with `setValue` or how?

Comment: no, you don't have to use ``setValue`` in order to set the ``defaultValue``. Make an object of ``defaultValue`` in ``useEffect``. Define all the neccasory fields like in your case ``name``. Do something like ``defaultValue.name = 'Kristof'`` and at last do ``reset({...defaultVales})``. Also checkout `reset`` for more clarification.
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

Comment: Here's the code sandbox link I've created.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-mclean-lbjdd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Yes, you were right! It is much simpler and also easier to reset the form with reset and not use setValue at all!

Thanks for your help! Maybe if you can make this comment an answer, I can accept that.

Comment: Glad I could help you out. I've posted an answer to your question. Check it out and let me know if it requires any edits. Happy coding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would be easier for you to use `reset()` to set the `defaultValue` of your form. Here's an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-mclean-lbjdd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) I have prepared for you.

All you have to do is to create an object inside `useEffect()`. Set your all default values using that object. At last spread that `defaultValues` object inside `reset()`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let defaultValues = {};
    defaultValues.firstName = "Kristof";
    defaultValues.lastName = "Rado";
    reset({ ...defaultValues });
  }, []);

  <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="First Name" />
  <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Comment: Thanks! The only missing piece in the docs was the difference between `setValue` and `reset`.
However if you pre-fill a form I would now suggest for everyone to use `reset`. That way you can update all fields with one call (setValue can update 1 field) and also the `dirtyFields` and `isDirty` will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! reset did the trick for me, I was trying to initialize the form values inside useFocusEffect but when running validation it was always empty, doing reset did the trick with the pre-fill

Comment: Be sure not to reset with null or undefined values because it might reset to the previous default value instead of the new one.

Comment: doesn't look like a crutch?

Answer (score 1):

For future generations, remember to pass and set the `value` prop on you `TextInput`. I didn't do that and couldn't figure out why the value is set, but not displayed.

Comment: how would that look like in the context of the example provided ?

Comment: @jmiguel77 it concerns controlled components only, refer to the docs to learn which control props do what - ref, onClick, value etc.