# react hook form defaultValues not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Here is my code ... I want to set default value of a input field by react-hook-form
but its showing me the variable(problemName) value "undefine" ... I am checking its value in console.log(problemName) ...its showing my expected value

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SingleProble = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { problemNames } = useParams();
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/problems/math/${problemNames}`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data)
        })
}, [problemNames])

const { problemName, score, problemDetails, level, problemAns, tried, solved, failed } = data

const defaultValues = {name:problemName}
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues })
```

Comment: Where are you printing `problemName` and it shows a value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change React-Hook-Form defaultValue with useEffect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242657/how-to-change-react-hook-form-defaultvalue-with-useeffect)

Answer (score 1):

this is because you have your `useForm` initialized with `{name: undefined}` as the `data` is async. What you can do is either: 1) wrap the Form in a parent which fetches data and then passes data as a prop (or sets data in a Provider).  or, 2) if you want to keep everything in 1 component you can re-write as:

```
const SingleProble = () => {
const { problemNames } = useParams();
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const defaultValues = {name:problemName}
const { setValue } = useForm({ defaultValues })


useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/problems/math/${problemNames}`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data)
            setValue('name', res.data.problemName)
        })
}, [problemNames])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this stackoverflow answer. Answer explains how it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667544/15052600

And you can also take a look at the similar question itself.

[Set default values in React Hook Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663158/set-default-values-in-react-hook-form)