# I can't change date via react-hooks-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, frontend

I made this component

```
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="DOB"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DatePicker
                  defaultValue={defaultvalues.DOB}
                  id="DOB"
                  name="DOB"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  label={t("Date of Bearth")}
                  value={field.value}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    field.onChange(value);
                  }}
                  {...register("DOB", {})}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
          />
```

Problem is that if I change the DOB it display me this error and submit send old DOB (from defaultValues).

> peError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell when you don't show all relevant code in your question. Some reading in this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268317/14072498